# Android AIR code to Prompt engaged users to rate your app

Tags: android, flash, air, rating

How to Prompt engaged users to rate your app in android AIR. I have two games in the google play. Their download counts is increasing fast but too little ratings.

So I thought this would be a good idea to "Prompt engaged users to rate your app".

Comment: You will need to create a dialog for that.. a reminder (dont remind me again, remind me again in 2 days). Unless you get better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way to do that with AS3- see link below:

http://blog.flexwiz.net/tip-rate-my-app-air-style/